# Can't pass value in segue using protocol: destination is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, core-data

As I navigate my app, I'm trying to pass my `NSManagedObjectContext` to my child `ViewControllers` (i.e. dependency injection)

I created a protocol `ManagedObjectContextDependent`

```
protocol ManagedObjectContextDependent {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! { get set }
}
```

My custom `ViewControllers` adopt the protocol. For example:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, ManagedObjectContextDependent {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
}
```

Then on `prepareForSeqgue` I pass it along. This works fine.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? MyTableViewController {
            destinationVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        }
 }
```

But if I try to cast the destination instead to a `ManagedObjectContextDependent`, I can't:

**Cannot assign to property: 'destinationVC' is a 'let' constant**

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ManagedObjectContextDependent {
            destinationVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        }
}
```

I'm trying to refactor this code to make it generic-- any two `ManagedObjectDependent` classes can pass on a segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you declare your protocol as a `class` protocol, Swift assumes that it might be implemented by a `struct` or an `enum`.  In those cases, the variable assigned with `let` cannot be modified.

To fix this add `class` to your `protocol` declaration:

```
protocol ManagedObjectContextDependent: class {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! { get set }
}
```